# How to define a struct that is Send+Sync and is holding a io::Write member

Tags: rust

I've a struct that needs to `impl` a given trait that itself is `Send + Sync`; I also want the struct to hold any generic type that is `io::Write` (but not necessarily `Send + Sync`). I'm completely lost on how to formulate that.

Let's say

```
struct Foobar<T> {
    stream: T,
}

impl<T> Foobar<T>
    where T: io::Write
{
    pub fn new(stream: T) -> Foobar<T> {
        Foobar { stream: stream }
    }
}
```

That would not be `Send + Sync` to begin with so we can (can't) do

```
struct Foobar<T> {
    stream: Arc<Mutex<T>>,
}

impl<T> Foobar<T>
    where T: io::Write
{
    pub fn new(stream: T) -> Foobar<T> {
        Foobar { stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream)) }
    }
}

impl<T> mycrate::TraitRequiringSendSync for Foobar<T> {
    fn write(the_msg: &str) {
        self.stream.lock().unwrap().write(...)
    }
}
```

I'm completely lost on how to formulate that the inner type of `stream` needs to be `io::Write` and the overall `impl` of `Foobar`is `Send + Sync`.

Comment: The question shows signs of poor editing. You had missing braces and the names are mismatched (`Logger`?). Please take the time to create a [MCVE]. This shows that you have done the appropriate work ahead of time and that you respect the time of those that might want to answer your question.

Comment: Additionally, I believe your question could be reasonably broadened to "how can I wrap a non-`Send + Sync` type to make it `Send + Sync`?". There shouldn't be anything special about `io::Write` or even the trait. Those are good details to include in the body of the post, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you just need to constrain `T` to be `Write + Send`:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::io::Write;

//This is the important bit
struct Foobar<T: Write + Send> {
    stream: Arc<Mutex<T>>,
}

impl<T: Write + Send> Foobar<T>
{
    pub fn new(stream: T) -> Foobar<T> {
        Foobar { stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream)) }
    }
}

trait Test: Write + Send {}

//verify that Foobar is Send + Sync
impl<T: Write + Send> Test for Foobar<T> { }
```

Comment: I don't want the inner type to be constrained to be Sync+Send

Comment: @user2722968 can be be constrained to Send? It will have to be if you are going to wrap it in a Mutex.

Comment: @WesleyWiser isn't the whole point of `Arc` to make the inner type `Send`?

Comment: @AykutYilmaz "isn’t the point of Arc<T> thread safety? The key is this: Arc<T> makes it thread safe to have multiple ownership of the same data, but it doesn’t add thread safety to its data." https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#thread-safety

Comment: Oh okay, then I misunderstood something!